# Sequelize JS - protecting properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

```
var Game = sequelize.define('Game', {

    secretField: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    }
}, { 
    getterMethods: {
        secretFieldHash: function () {
            return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(this.getDataValue('secretField')).digest('hex');
        }
    }
});
```

Above model is an example of my current model. What I'm trying to achieve is the following.

I have a 'secretField' that I sometimes need to use in my backend code, but I also sometimes want to show *only* the hashed version of that field in the frontend.

Is this possible?

Another example for my problem would be a player model. You don't want to send the password to the frontend but you sometimes need to use it in the backend (ie. for comparison if the user entered the correct password).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look forward to the following (not implemented yet): https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1462

For now, you could overwrite the toJSON method like this:

```
{
  instanceMethods: {
    toJSON: function () {
      var resp = this.prototype.toJSON();
      resp.secretField = hash(resp.secretField);

      return resp;
    }
  }
}
```

In this way the secret field will be available to your backend but will be removed when the object is converted to JSON and sent to the end user.

Comment: That indeed worked. Thanks alot. 

Do you also happen to know when exactly toJSON() gets called? I'm not calling it anywhere manually.

Comment: When you are sending data to the client it has to be converted to JSON. Let's assume you are using express. When you call res.json(200, response), somewhere down in the code express calls JSON.stringify(response), which checks whether response has a toJSON method, and if it has invokes that.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior

Comment: Thanks again! I understand it now.

Will it be possible to show the original secretField value later? The way my game works I need to show the hash before the game starts and with original value when it has ended.

Comment: For some reason with this answer my code throws an error: can not call toJSON of undefined? Am I missing something?

Comment: @cspiegl It seems like the Sequelize API has changed recently, breaking this solution

Comment: @AlexanderKuzmin Any news on this? I'm struggling with the same problems.

Comment: Try `this.constructor.super_.prototype.toJSON`

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier actually I have the problem that toJSON doesn't get  called when the model is nested/included in a find-Call do you have any suggestions? (using Sequelize2.0.0-rc2) This did work for version beta8

Comment: Never mind I found a solution: The parent model now must also implement `toJSON()` in order to call the nested `toJSON()` methods.

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier What about using `this.get({plain:true})` in place of `this.prototype.toJSON()`?